# Remove lines based on duplicates described by regex?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, substitution

Let's say I have a file like this:

```
apple   2018-01-01
apple cider 2018-01-05
apple cider 2017-01-06
lemon   2016-12-30
lemon   2017-12-31
lemon juice 2018-03-12
lemon pie 2018-03-30
```

I.e., it has 1 or more text columns, and then a date. And some text entries are duplicated for the [different] dates. Now, I want to delete these duplicates:

```
apple   2018-01-01
apple cider 2017-01-06
lemon   2016-12-30
lemon juice 2018-03-12
lemon pie 2018-03-30
```

Be it in one column, it'd possible to use [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171091/remove-lines-based-on-duplicates-within-one-column-without-sort). But what if instead of looking in a particular column, I must look for duplicates via a regex? Can `awk` handle this? Or are there any other workarounds?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain why a regex is needed.

Comment: what is the criteria to delete the duplicates??? Which value should be kept?

Comment: @Allan, if text before the date is a duplicate of a previously existing text before the date, then it should be deleted.

Comment: @agc, Well, I thought that capturing the text before the date (which is the one to be inspected to have duplicates) is easier with a regex (like, `^([A-Za-z ]*)\d+`). If that's not necessary and there are other ways, then I all for it and would be grateful for a hint :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\s+2"}{a[$1]=2""$2}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file.input | sort
apple 2018-01-01
apple cider 2017-01-06
lemon 2017-12-31
lemon juice 2018-03-12
lemon pie 2018-03-30
```

This solution will only keep when duplicate appears the last value that appear.
If you want to change the behavior you can add some conditions to replace the value if it is more recent for example.

You can also sort the file before doing the operation.

Explanations:

- `FS="\\s+2` to setup the field separator between the first column and the date (I suppose that the date starts by a 2)
- `{a[$1]=2""$2}` Then you create an array where the indexes are the first column and you assign the value when they appear.
- `END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}` will just print the result

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *file* is already sorted, then:

1. Using `rev` and `uniq`:

   ```
   rev file | uniq -f1 | rev
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   apple   2018-01-01
   apple cider 2018-01-05
   lemon   2016-12-30
   lemon juice 2018-03-12
   lemon pie 2018-03-30
   ```
2. If the goal is to delete the opposite set of duplicates, add a set
   of `tac`s:

   ```
   rev file | tac | uniq -f1 | tac | rev
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   apple   2018-01-01
   apple cider 2017-01-06
   lemon   2017-12-31
   lemon juice 2018-03-12
   lemon pie 2018-03-30
   ```
3. If the goal is to keep the oldest date:

   ```
   rev file | sed 's/ /:/' | rev | sort -t: -k 1,2gr | 
   tr : ' ' | rev | uniq -f1 | rev
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   apple   2018-01-01
   apple cider 2017-01-06
   lemon   2016-12-30
   lemon juice 2018-03-12
   lemon pie 2018-03-30
   ```